# How the Photorec works internally and How to use it in Ubuntu14.04?

Tags: data-recovery, ubuntu-14.04, file-recovery

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 in my machine. By accidentally I've deleted some files. So I search in Internet about,how to recover the deleted files. So I got a solution as photorec. But I have some doubt in this,

- How does it internally work?
- If the file header is also lost, then how it will recover the data?
- Why the recovered file name is different from original file?
- How it will find the first block of the deleted file?

For that I read in the link, [How PhotoRec works](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). But I can't understand it clearly, So any one please explain it and clarify my doubts. Also I need to know the steps to use it.

Comment: “If the file header is also lost, then how it will recover the data?” In fact, it won't. You are confusing a file header with a file *record.* Data carving works by scanning for magic numbers of known file types so headers must be there. File records are completely ignored, most of the time. Photorec is a bit smarter in that it scans MFT entries with resident `$DATA` attributes for small files in NTFS, but those are special cases.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Photorec a lot, and while it is hit-or-miss at times it always seems to recover more than I imagined.  I can't speak for how it internally works, although their [site](https://www.cgsecurity.org/) says you can download the source there.

When you delete a file, the OS *generally* does not actually wipe the data.  Instead, it removes the file's metadata (data about the file) from the file table on that partition.  It's the equivalent to tearing a page out of a phonebook: the people are still there but we can't call them because we don't know their name, number, or where they live.  This is why the filenames it recovers are not the original names.

Without a header, it attempts to scan the drive for identifiers of particular file types.  For instance, Word files, JPEGs, etc all have a certain pattern of data in the file which identifies it as such.  Photorec sees this and realizes it's that type of file.

Give it a try and see what it recovers.  Expect to let it run for a good many hours, depending on the size of your drive.  And, of course, make certain you are recovering *to* a different drive than your files were deleted *from*.  Otherwise you will overlay the data you are trying to get back.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But still I have a small doubt. You said that, it will remove only meta data. Then how the photorec will identify the start and end of file and recover it. Can you pls explain this for me

Comment: Start of the file is easy (relatively speaking).  JPEGs for instance always start with a certain hexadecimal pattern.  PDFs contain a consistent header.  Other files have a consistent hexadecimal pattern or header which identifies them as a certain type of file.  Photorec scans the sectors on the disk for those headers, which allow it to recognize that that data is the start of a file.  Assuming there is not a great deal of fragmentation it should be able to keep reading until it gets either another file header or an end to the data stream it is expecting.  Therefore it knows it is at the end.

Comment: “Instead, it removes the file's metadata (data about the file)” In most cases, not even that (unless it has to be reallocated). See for instance MFT entries in NTFS where a single bit is flipped when an entry is marked as deleted.

Comment: Ok, Then where the Jpeg's hexadecimal pattern or PDF's consistent header or the header to identify certain type of file will be stored?. Also while overwriting the data on the same sector, these values will get affect or not. Incase if it get affect, then how the data will be recover?

Comment: The thing to appreciate about data recovery is there are no guarantees that you will get anything useful back.  Once new data begins to be written over the old it is not possible via software to make a recovery.  So, as you alluded to, once the hexadecimal patterns and headers are written over it may not be possible to detect that file's presence any longer.  You would then be entering the realm of data forensics and attempting to determine the previous magnetic state of those bits, which is far beyond the capabilities of PhotoRec.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what your doubts are, so that we can try to understand how to help you with them?

Comment: @Ganapathy of course you cannot recover overwritten data. Nobody can. FBI can't. CIA can't. [Insert name of favorite US agency that illegally spies on people overseas here] can't. The things about magnetic traces of single bits seen in the TV series are science fiction.

Comment: My Doubt is,
 1. Where the jpeg's hexdecimal pattern or header will be stored?
 Because using this only the recovery software will find the file starting position and recover the file. 2.If this informations are stored in normal sector, it may have chance to overwritten. If it is overwritten, What will happen?

Comment: 3. What is MFT or NTFS and where it is?

Comment: 1) it's in the data sectors.  Photorec scans for physical data on the disk, regardless of FAT/MFT.  2) Overwritten data is lost, which could cause partial or truncated recovery of the file or could manifest as file corruption.  3) MFT is the Master File Table, it's similar in kind to the FAT used in FAT-based file sysyems.  NTFS is the file system of choice for modern Windows systems.

Comment: @ Andrea Lazzarotto, Thanks for your valuable reply